# In Terraform , how to refer to components created in root module in included modules

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

The below sample is given to give an idea about the question.

I have a resource group and EventHubNS created in the root module of the Terraform script

I have another module , called processingmodule ,that has function, EventHub and few other aggregated components.

So the Root module is as below  -
Create Azure Resource Group
Create EventHubNS
Create processingModule

If the event hub was created in the root module,  the eventhub resource is created using below resource block

```
resource "azurerm_eventhub" "eventhub" {
  name                = "${var.eventhubname}-eh"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.eventhubns.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.RG.name
  partition_count     = var.eventhub_partitioncount
  message_retention   = 5
 
}
```

If I write the module, the namespace_name and resource_group_name cannot be referred as shown below

```
namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.eventhubns.name
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.RG.name
```

Instead, the namespace_name should be referred through variable.

```
namespace_name      = var.eventhubnsname
resource_group_name = var.resourcegroupname
```

So question is - is there anyway to refer to the resources created in the root module from the processingcomponent module

Comment: Can you provide the full code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Modules do not have access to resources in the parent, unless those resources are passed in as variables to the module.

Comment: This would mean that i would have to go with variables? Is there a way to extract the names through some other mechanism like data ?

Comment: Variables are the method for doing this. If you try to reference something via data in the child module that is being created in the parent module you will get Terraform plan errors because the data you are trying to lookup in the module hasn't been created by the parent at the time the plan is generated.